# Sticky header slide into fixed position from top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've set up my sticky header to pop into the top fixed position but i want it animated so it slides from the top off screen down to the current top 0 position when scrolled.

I tried adding the transition css but it seems to slide up into position due to the "normal" header not being at the same position to start off with. It has a margin added to the top so i guess that's why the animation is showing it slide up into top 0 position.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if( $(window).scrollTop() > $('.header').offset().top + 300 && !($('.header').hasClass('stickyheader'))){
    $('.header').addClass('stickyheader');
    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0){
    $('.header').removeClass('stickyheader');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jc0807/euyLvesr/4/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just animate the transition with jquery:

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  if( $(window).scrollTop() > $('.header').offset().top + 300 && !($('.header').hasClass('stickyheader'))){
    $('.header').addClass('stickyheader').animate({"top":"0%"});
  } else if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0){
    $('.header').removeClass('stickyheader');
  }
});
```

CS:

```
.stickyheader{
   ...
   top: -100%;
   ...
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/euyLvesr/5/)

Increased slide time:

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/euyLvesr/6/)

Fixed slide down after scrolling back up

[NEW FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/euyLvesr/7/)

Comment: thanks for your reply, but the animate doesn't seem to make any difference, i don't see it "slide" down into position it still "jumps" into position. Can easing be applied?

Comment: it's definitely slides down, i made it slower for you incase there is some lag in your browser or something. Updated fiddle above

Comment: i can see the animate when i first load the site and scroll down but if i scroll back up and try scrolling down again it doesn't animate and jumps.

Comment: ah, i understand. The `top` property just needed to be reset when the class was removed. Updated fiddle above